# Discord.JS Reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a ticket bot and I would like it so that you react to a message to create a ticket. I can make the message but when I use `bot.on('messageReactionAdd')` if my bot restarts it won't detect that a reaction has been added unless you make a new message and react to a message that has been created since the bot has been online. This is a problem for me and I know it's fixable. I've tried google searches and couldn't fix the problem. Can anyone here help me?

Comment: When the bot starts up, instruct it to fetch messages that you need it to keep track of. Presumably you have this "special message" in a dedicated channel that will never have any other messages, so you can just fetch messages in that channel and Discord.js will keep track of new reactions on it.

Comment: How do you fetch messages in discord.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from Discord.js v12, you can enable [partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions) on the bot that allow it to send events for unfetched messages, with the tradeoff that you have to fetch the message yourself at the start of the handler:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
// Make sure you instantiate the client with the correct settings
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    // When we receive a reaction we check if the reaction is partial or not
    if (reaction.partial) {
        // If the message this reaction belongs to was removed the fetching might result in an API error, which we need to handle
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            // Return as `reaction.message.author` may be undefined/null
            return;
        }
    }
    // Now the message has been cached and is fully available
    console.log(`${reaction.message.author}'s message "${reaction.message.content}" gained a reaction!`);
    // The reaction is now also fully available and the properties will be reflected accurately:
    console.log(`${reaction.count} user(s) have given the same reaction to this message!`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this however you want, but here is an example for you:

```
message.channel.send("React test!").then(messageReaction => {
    messageReaction.react("✅");
    messageReaction.react("⛔");
  });
```